# Conmutators and Jacobi's Identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I've come across an exercise asking me to calculate:

$$[[A,B],[C,D]]$$

knowing $[A,C]=[B,D]=0$ and $[A,D]=[B,C]=1$

I've already solved it by "brute force", separating the commutator as follows:

$$[[A,B],[C,D]]=[AB,CD]-[AB,DC]-[BA,CD]+[BA,DC]=0$$

However, I've found out there's a more elegant way to do it, and that's with Jacobi's identity:

$$[A,[B,C]]+[B,[C,D]]+[C,[D,A]]+[D,[A,B]]=0$$

but I can't wrap my head around it. How could I use this identity to solve the exercise in a more elegant way?

Comment: Convince yourself $A\sim \partial_x, ~D\sim x, ~B\sim\partial_y,~C\sim y$ with $[x,y]=0$ is a faithful realization/representation, whence your top commutator trivially vanishes. You may dress this up in turgid symmetry-antisymmetry arguments, but you'll be replicating the same combinatorics.

Comment: I’ve never seen that version of the “Jacobi identity”, and I don’t believe that it’s true. Expand it and see for yourself that the 16 terms don’t cancel. For example, the first term is $ABC$. Where is $-ABC$ going to come from?

Comment: I’m guessing that you were told that you could use the Jacobi identity, and you incorrectly generalized it. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity#Related_identities) has a generalization to four operators, but I don’t know if it’s useful for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not "found" something which is not even wrong. What you *should* have found is your top line reducing to
$$
A[B,[C,D]]+ [A,[C,D]]B - B[A,[C,D]]-[B,[C,D]]A,
$$
where , now, it should be evident to you that each double commutator automatically vanishes by the Jacobi identity ***for each***, e.g,,
$$
[B,[C,D]]= -[C,[D,B]]-[D,[B,C]]= -[B,0]- [D,1]=0,
$$
etc.

If you understand faithful realizations, you might short-cut through the above comment.